# Converting from UTC Time to Local Time

Tags: c#, datetime, utc, dynamics-crm-online

I'm working with the Microsoft CRM 2013 SDK for a project (MS CRM Online) that I'm working on. 
As I've discovered everything that is generated back via the SDK shows in UTC time.

I live in Australia (QLD) and I need to add 10 hours to this to represent the time in my timezone.

I'm pulling a datetime field from the SDK and displaying that datetime into a ASP.NET Repeater. 
I've wrapped a function around this to convert to the local timezone, however it fails with the following

"No overload for method `AddAuQLDToUTC` takes two arguments"

The function I'm using in the code behind file

```
public DateTime AddAuQLDToUTC(DateTime value) 
{
   DateTime UpdatedDate = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc);
   UpdatedDate = UpdatedDate.ToLocalTime();
   return UpdatedDate;
}
```

I can wrap this function around System.DateTime.Now and it adds 10 hours to this as it thinks it's UTC as I've add to the function which is what I expected. This proves that the function is working but for some odd reason it fails when wrapped around the repeater like below

```
<%# AddAuQLDToUTC(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "new_InspectionDate"), "{0:D}")%>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you not just call `SpecifyKind` and then `ToLocalTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method take one input and you supplied two argument when you call method. It should be like this

```
<%# AddAuQLDToUTC((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "new_InspectionDate"))%>
```

if you want to format as {0:D} then

```
 <%# String.Format("{0:D}",AddAuQLDToUTC((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"new_InspectionDate"))) %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm learning C# and have always done VB therefore the reason why I missed this off. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Next question - is that I've now added 10 hours to the UTC date but need to just extract the time part & also the just the DAY MONTH).

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to say but if you want that time properly convert to utc or local , first you have to check that what is datetime zone of value that you pass as input to function.

Comment: Basically, now that the 10 hours for AU timezone has been added by making the change you requested - I need to now extract just the time component (i.e. 14:00). Another function would be just extracting (29 Dec). I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes and you can do that by string format if only usage is to display on page. http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/